# Convert 14 digit time to readable format

Tags: php, datetime

I have the date as this:
20170508215900

How would I convert that to say:
Monday 8th May - 21:59:00

I realise this is probably a very basic question but I have searched and can't seem to find a way. I tried strtotime but that just turned it into seconds..

```
$my_end = 20170508215900;
echo "REAL TIME:";
echo strtotime($my_end);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would probably use [datetime::createfromformat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$string = '20170508215900';
$format = 'YmdHis';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $string);

echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format( 'l jS M - H:i:s' );
// Monday 8th May - 21:59:00
```

$date will now contain a DateTime object for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Prints something like](https://eval.in/790158): `Sunday 1st of January 2012 03:14:20 PM`

```
<?php
    echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", strtotime("20120101151420"));
?>
```

More about date() format http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php